# *ngif Comparison date with angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to compare two date and I used with this method ngif
But it does not work

```
   <ion-row *ngFor="let ch of cheval1 ">
       {{ch[0].annee }}
            <ion-col *ngFor="let m of members">
              <b *ngIf="ch[0].annee == m.Course.date |date : 'yyyy' ">    {{m.Course.date |date : 'yyyy' }}  </b>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

Comment: try wrapping it in braces: `*ngIf="ch[0].annee == (m.Course.date | date : 'yyyy')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `*ngIf` to call out to a function in your component:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let ch of cheval1 ">
   {{ch[0].annee }}
   <ion-col *ngFor="let m of members">
      <b *ngIf="yearsAreEqual(ch[0].annee, m.Course.date)">    {{m.Course.date |date : 'yyyy' }}  </b>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>


yearsAreEqual(year, date){
    return year === date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: hi Tyler ,please can you help me for my problem

Comment: hi ,please can you help me for my problem :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919676/calculating-sum-of-elements-by-date-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2-ngfor

Comment: Isn't it suggested by angular to not call methods and functions from the template because they will get called anytime any change on the component model happens?

Comment: Not necessarily recommended, and I certainly would do that sparingly, but it does work.  The alternative would be to transform your data in the collection before rendering and filter the data out.